# Sequelize associations (join) erorr: Error: Unknown column

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have 2 simple tables:

```
table: wp_posts 
PK ID
post_title

table: wp_postmeta 
PK post_id
meta_key
meta_value
```

Running this code:

```
wp_posts.hasMany(wp_postmeta , { foreignKey: "post_id" });
wp_postmeta.belongsTo(wp_posts , { foreignKey: "ID" });

wpPostsData = await wp_posts .findAll({
      include: [wp_postmeta ]
    });
```

Generates the following (i can see that in the terminal):

```
Executing (default): SELECT `wp_posts`.`ID`, `wp_posts`.`post_author`, `wp_posts`.`post_title`, `wp_postmeta`.`post_id` AS `wp_postmeta.post_id`, `wp_postmeta`.`meta_key` AS `wp_postmeta.meta_key`, `wp_postmeta`.`meta_value` AS `wp_postmeta.meta_value`, `wp_postmeta`.`ID` AS `wp_postmeta.ID` FROM `wp_posts` AS `wp_posts` LEFT OUTER JOIN `wp_postmeta` AS `wp_postmeta` ON `wp_posts`.`ID` = `wp_postmeta`.`post_id` WHERE `wp_posts`.`post_type` = 'product';
```

Ending in this error:

```
parent: Error: Unknown column 'wp_postmeta.ID' in 'fie…    at Packet.asError (c:\Users\yonatan\OneD…, original: Error: Unknown column 'wp_postmeta.ID' in 'fi…   at Packet.asError (c:\Users\yonatan\OneD…, sql: 'SELECT `wp_posts`.`ID`, `wp_posts`.`post_autho…_id` WHERE `wp_posts`.`post_type` = 'product';', parameters: {…}, …}
```

Why is Sequelize using `wp_postmeta.ID` in the select statements?
It's getting it right in the `join` part where it uses `wp_postmeta.post_id`.
So why mix the tables fields after it?

Comment: According to [this diagram](https://codex.wordpress.org/images/2/2a/WP3.9.4-ERD.png) they PK of `wp_postmeta` is `meta_id` not `ID`. `post_id` is a FK referencing `wp_posts.ID`.

Comment: Correct, and this is what's connecting this 2 tables. Post and meta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to indicate the same foreign key column in both paired associations (hasMany/belongsTo) because actually you have only one foreign key column (in `wp_postmeta`) and the other column in `wp_posts` is PK (by default).

```js
wp_posts.hasMany(wp_postmeta , { foreignKey: "post_id" });
wp_postmeta.belongsTo(wp_posts , { foreignKey: "post_id" });
```

There is no need to indicate the column from 1 side table of 1:N relationship in an association because usually it's the PK column. If you want to use other column instead of PK that has a unique constraint/index then you need to indicate it as well in both associations in `sourceKey` option.

Comment: Thanks, Anatoly! There is no error now, but I still get no results. I't stuck and looks like the promise is never resolved. Any idea why is that?

Comment: Did you try to execute SQL generated by this query?

Comment: Yes, I used it on myphpadmin and it works well.

Comment: Are you sure you get all records in `myphpadmin`? Maybe it's just first N records only? Is there a possibility that this query returns too many records?

Comment: You are correct! it returns over 300k records. I waited for about 6 min and got them. adding a where clause did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: Can you maybe write a detailed explanation of how to use Sequelize relations? join, foreignKey, PK, include, and all that stuff? I found the documentation very confusing. And I think it can really help the community. 
And again, thanks!

Comment: Hmm, it will take much time and again SO is about Q&A and not as a reference. You can ask more questions with tag `sequelize` and maybe I answer them in some cases more widely than usual.